# Bundle stderr: ArgumentError: "...tmp/pids/unicorn.pid" not writable. How to solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I am deploying code with Capistrano and while the process, I get the error that

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@IP: Exception while executing as deployer@IP: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn)
bundle stderr: ArgumentError: directory for pid=/home/deployer/apps/project/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid not writable
```

How do I solve this issue? Do I need to set something in the `deploy.rb` file?

I've tried to manually create the `pids` directory, set permissions on 777 (`mkdir -m 777 pids`), but nothing helped.

How can I make that directory writable?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706088/unicorn-unable-to-write-pid-file).

Also are you sure the path is right? I think pids dir should be under the `_shared dir_` and not the current (which is a symbolic link to a `realease/something`)

If the path is hardcoded try changing it to `/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`